# How do the Array methods below differ from each other in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am getting confused with the Array methods below. Can anyone help me understand how differently they work from each other with the help of simple snippet?

- `array.sort` and `array.sort { | a,b | block }`
- `array.to_a` and `array.to_ary`
- `array.size` and `array.length`
- `array.reverse` and `array.reverse_each {|item| block }`
- `array.fill(start [, length] ) { |index| block }` and
  `array.fill(range) { |index| block }`

Comment: Don't write "Array class methods" in your case. It means a different thing. what you mean is not class methods, they are instance methods.

Comment: I am not one of the downvoters, but at a guess the reason is because this is the kind of question you can find the answer to just by reading [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html). If you *have* read the documentation, but still don't get it then you should give details of which bit is confusing to you.

Comment: Yes,I am bit confused with some of those methods,as the documents does not put there a small codes to explain each of the methods. Can you please up vote me? I am trying to put some codes in my question so that it clears to you where is the pain?

Comment: I didn't downvote, either, but if you hover over the downvote arrow, you get a tooltip which lists some of the possible legitimate reasons for downvoting and one of the reasons given is "this question does not show any research effort", which this question clearly doesn't. Also, although this is generally *not* considered a valid reason for downvoting, some people *do* downvote for bad grammar, bad spelling or hard to understand language, which your question also has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [documentation for Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html).

**sort:**

```
a=[3,1,2]
a.sort              # => [1, 2, 3] 
a.sort{|a,b| b<=>a} # => [3, 2, 1]
```

use the second one if you need some custom way to sort elements.

**to_a vs. to_ary:**

```
class Foo < Array;end
b=Foo[1,2]
b.to_ary.class # returns self
b.to_a.class   # converts to array
```

size and length are exactly the same.

reverse_each is pretty much the same as reverse.each.

If you want to fill only a part of the array, you can call Array.fill either with a `range` or `start,length`. Those are just different ways to achieve the same:

```
(["a"]*10).fill("b",2..7)
(["a"]*10).fill("b",2,6)
```

both return `["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a"]`.

Comment: this is not post related queries,but i think i need to know about the [ruby doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/). i am newbie to this platform. when i opened the online doc found two thinks `Core API` and `Standard Library API` . Why such separations? how base class differs from standard classes as the doc showing. Your little help might able me to understand and utilize the docs in an efficient way.

Comment: The base classes pretty much make up the language itself. They are always available to you. Functionality of the standard library is only available to you when you explicitly require it. (For example network stuff is only needed if you are doing network things.) - The third type of functionality are gems, which are kind of "third party extensions" for all kind of things. In that case you have to first install the corresponding gem and then require what you need.